# Bbl file not generated

Tags: subfiles, bbl

I use textmaker and I have a problem. The bbl file is not generated from the bib file. How can I solve that?

Comment: bbl files are generated by bibtex or biber, have you run either of those?, if there are errors they will be recorded in their log files (.blg for bibtex)

Comment: Crosspost on LaTeX-community.

Comment: If you are using `biblatex` with Biber, please refer to [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). If you need more help we need to see an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) an explanation on how you compile your file as well as warning/error messages you get. Note that you *do not* compile the `.bib` file, you run BibTeX on the `.aux` file and Biber on the `.bcf` - although it is better to run `biber <basename>`/`bibitex <basename>` without file extension.

Answer (score 6):

If you use TeXMaker, you should run bibtex or biblatex to generate the bbl file. It is not done automatically.

What I used to do, is first run `pdflatex` and then `bibtex` followed by two times `pdflatex`. Because Bibtex needs the auxiliary file to generate the bbl file.

Comment: What you used to works today, too.
1-) Run pdfLaTeX alone and generate aux
2-) Run bibtex alone and generate .bbl
3-) Run pdfLaTeX alone and retrieve list of references
4-) Run pdfLaTeX finally and alone, and put in-text citations.

Answer (score 3):

Not familiar with this IDE but in `kile` I use a separate hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to the one for PDFLaTeX: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>

This may be a related issue. Failing that, run in the console or command-line:

```
bibtex file.tex #generates a bbl
latex file.tex #generates aux,dvi etc
pdflatex file.tex # generates a PDF
```

Running BibTeX on a .tex file will generate a bbl based on the bibliography and citation inputs called within the .tex file (as it only lists those cited).

Comment: BibTeX without using latex before is pointless. The other answer explains why.

Comment: Indeed but I presume the OP has already run LaTeX if they know that a .bbl file isn't generated. They should already have an .aux file. So they run BibTeX to generate a bibliography and the update the PDF to include it. This should suffice to typeset an existing document after updating it.